# MongoDB - Join on multiple condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For the below query

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA as A LEFT JOIN TableB as B ON (A.id = B.id AND A.name =B.name)
```

Mongo:

```
TableA.aggregate([
    {"$lookup": {
                "from": "TableB",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "b"
                }},
                { "$match": {  "name":"b.name" } }

])
```

For the above query, required output is not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer [this sample playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uJsWJa29ysJ)

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "inventory",
      let: {
        id: "$_id",
        item: "$item"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$eq": [
                "$_id",
                "$$id"
              ],
              "$eq": [
                "$sku",
                "$$item"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "outputs"
    }
  }
])
```

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)